# How do you use the right-hand rule for glm::cross?

Tags: opengl, math, glm-math

When I do cross(vec3(0,0,1),vec3(1,0,0)), I get vec3(0,1,0).

Can anyone explain to me why am I not getting vec3(0,-1,0)?
If you put your index finger forward and middle finger pointing to the right, the thumb points down. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing -- in a right-hand system where Z goes "forward" and X goes "to the right", then Y goes towards the bottom. So the result is a positive quantity in Y's direction.

Comment: "*If you put your index finger forward and middle finger pointing to the right*" What does "forward" mean here? Does it mean "away from you"? Because "forward" usually means "towards you". I find the easiest way to figure out where +Z is is to remember `X cross Y = Z`. So in a right-handed coordinate system, put your index and middle fingers along X and Y, and that's where Z is. If X is to the right, and Y is up, then Z is *towards you* in a right-handed coordinate system.

Comment: By forward I meant away from you like walking forward. The way my code is done, forwards is positive Z and upwards is positive Y. So in academics Z is backwards? That would explain my confusion.

Comment: To clarify, when I said I got vec3(0,1,0), I meant as the output of the program. Using the right hand rule I get vec3(0,-1,0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the correct answer.  If i, j, k are unit vectors in the x, y, z-directions, then:

```
i X j = k
j X k = i
k X i = j
```

Your example is the third one, so it's obvious that you should get a unit vector in the positive y-direction.

This is an example of a [permutation symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) - appropriate, since vectors are first order tensors.